# Java Infinite loop

Tags: java, while-loop

Can someone please advise why the inner loop of the code below will not exit? 
I've added an inner loop to check if input from the user of of a particular value and if not prompts for the correct input. When debugging the code and passing in a value which should force the loop to end it doesn't although I can see the correct value in the variable:

```
while (finished.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
        System.out.println("Enter a persons name");
        names = in.nextLine();
        writer.println(names);
        System.out.println("Finished? (Y/N)");
        finished = in.nextLine();
        while( !finished.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || !finished.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            System.out.println("Invalid choice; (Y/N)");
            finished = in.nextLine();
        }
}
```

Comment: Change `||` to `&&`. As it is with the logical OR, you'll ALWAYS be different to one or the other, so you'll never exit the loop.

Comment: or by de morgans, you can change to `!(finished.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || 
      !finished.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))`

Answer (score 0):

Every string is either not not equal to `y` or not equal to `n`. You probably meant to use the `&&` operator:

```
while(!finished.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && 
      !finished.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {

    // Code...
```